# Finding minimum of a function with N variables

Tags: c, c99, minimum, repeat

I'm trying to code an algorithm to locate the minimum of [Rosenbrock function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function) that may have N variables. When N = 2, I can easily figure it out. The code that I'm using for N = 2 is below:

```
double y,z,x, aux1, aux2;
double menor = INT_MAX;
y = INT_MIN;
x = INT_MIN;


while(x < INT_MAX)
{
    while(y < INT_MAX)
    {
        z = (1-x)*(1-x) + 100*(y - (x*x))*(y - (x*x));
        if(menor > z)
        {
            menor = z;
            aux1 = x;
            aux2 = y;
        }   
                
        y = y + 0.1;    
        
    }
    y = 0.1;
    x = x + 0.1;
}

printf("(x,y) : (%.2lf, %.2lf) Minimum value of z: %.2lf\n", aux1, aux2, menor);
```

This code is working fine and I'm summing y and x by 0.1 only because I already know what the minimum is given that function (it's on (1,1)). It takes a little while to run, but it works. My problem is for N variable. When I think about this, what comes to my mind is that I will need N repetition structures. Here is the code as it's by now. Its not working, but it may give some idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
//Calculates the value of the Rosenbrock function given n(the number of variables)
double rosen(double *x, int n){

double y;

for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    y = y + 100*((x[i+1] - x[i]*x[i])*(x[i+1] - x[i]*x[i])) + (1 - x[i])*(1 - x[i]);
}   

return y;
}

int main(void){
double *x;
//n is the number of variables and it may change
int n = 3;

x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
double rosen(double *x, int n);

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x[i] = INT_MIN;
}
//That's the part where I can't figure out how to compute all the possibilities, changing the value of the last variable between INT_MIN AND INT_MAX. Then this variable gets the value of INT_MIN again and I will sum 0.1 to the variable antecedent, and then do all the process again to the last variable. And so on for all the N variables.
for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    while(x[i] < INT_MAX)
    {
        x[i] = x[i] + 0.1;
    }       
    x[i] = INT_MIN;
}
```

This code above probably contain some erros. But, the only thing I'm needing help is to vary all the values of the N variables. So, what I want to do is take the last variable and vary its value between INT_MIN and INT_MAX, summing 0.1(I know its really a long journey). After that, this variable will receive INT_MIN value again and the antecedent variable will vary by +0.1. Then, the last variable will vary from INT_MIN to INT_MAX again. And this will happen for all the N variables.

This is a problem that I'm trying to solve, to brute-force the value of a function to get its minimum. If you guys have some tips for me or some library that may help, I will be very gratefull.

Comment: The Rosenbrock function is used as a stress test for optimisation algorithms for a reason:   it is hard to define an approach that will converge quickly to a global minimum or maximum of that function.   Unless you introduce some constraints on your problem that contribute to converging faster on a solution (or, even better, allow an analytical solution) there is a fair bet you'll need to use a brute-force approach.   If that wasn't true, the Rosenbrock function wouldn't be used as a stress-test for optimisation algorithms.

Comment: Aside: I'd expect `double menor = DBL_MAX;` or `double menor = HUGE_VAL;` instead of `double menor = INT_MAX;`

Comment: Peter, that's just what I tried to clear in the last couple lines. I'm trying to find its minimum using brute-force. That's where I'm having a issue.

Comment: Aside, I get it. But this doesn't really matter to me. I'm using this INT_MIN only as a basis. In the most, I think I will just analyze the function between some small number. I guess my range will be from -5 to 5

Answer (score 0):

You can have a recursive function like the following (rough C):

```
void rosenMin(int maxDims, int currDim, double[] values, double* currMin)
{
    if (currDims == maxDims) {
        double rosenVal = rosen(values); // You need to implement this
        if (rosenVal < *currMax) {
            *currMin = rosenVal;
        }
    } else {
        for (double c = INT_MIN; c <= INT_MAX; c += 0.1) {
            values[currDim + 1] = c;
            rosenMin(maxDim, currDim + 1, values, currMin);
        }
    }
}

double[] values = new double[N] { 0 }; // Check with C syntax how this'll look!
double min = INT_MAX
rosenMin(N, 1, values, &min);
```